# Загрузка контента только после полной загрузки css

Tags: css, content

Здравствуйте.
Есть сайт на Drupal 7. Стили сжаты через модуль 'AdvAgg Compress CSS', но довольно часто контент загружается быстрее css и пользователю видна страница без css на несколько секунд.
Можно ли как-нибудь сделать чтобы контент загружался после полной загрузки css?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно такое происходит от неграмотной разработки проекта или использования очень большого количества сторонних библиотек. В таком случае ставят прелоадеры которые скрывают отображение станици для пользователя пока всё не подгрузится.. Если для вас критично что б оно не распадалось - вынесите критический css (до 14кБ) в head сайта. а всё остальное уже можно спустить вниз через отложенную загрузку. Контент "отложить" не получится, по причине того что html приходит раньше всего остального

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, чтобы загрузка стилей отображения происходила в голове (head) документа. Желательно первой в списке, если конечно вы не используете фреймворки. Тогда сразу после фреймворка. Потом остальные файлы и библиотеки.